# Android SDK. can MediaPlayer access file as MediaRecorder records

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am working on an Android application that can play back part of a file that MediaRecorder is saving.

Quick question.

Can MediaPlayer play from a .3gp file WHILE media recorder is in .start()?

I tried to do that but mediaPlayer's .prepare() fails every time I do so unless I stop mediaRecorder().

Do I need to set the file permissions to World-Readable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try it in recorder -

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(8);
recorder.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/tmp.ts);
```

Play this file after writing some data to it. This output format is MPEG-2TS only applicable from android version 3.0+;